# compact version of the dictionary

Tags: python

Wrote a function, it creates a modified dictionary:

```
  d1 = {1 : 2, 3 : 4, 5 : 4, 7 : 2, 9 : 4}
  def swap_dict (d):
    rd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
      rd[v] = rd.get(v, []) + [k]
    return rd
  print(swap_dict(d1))
```

How to make the function create a compact version of the dictionary. One word, keys are grouped by source value in tuples.

Example:

dictionary: `{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 4, 7: 2, 9: 4}`

compressed into: `{(3, 9, 5): 4, (1, 7): 2}`

Comment: How are you planning to use that? Now if you want to find the value for a given key you have to search all of the tuples, which isn't efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there; you can simply do:

```
>>> {tuple(v): k for k, v in swap_dict(d1).items()}                        
{(1, 7): 2, (3, 5, 9): 4}
```

This is a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) that is simply building a mapping between your list of keys and the values from the swapped dictionary.
More precisely, as keys of a dictionary need to be immutable, it is making a tuple out of your list.